# Правила пунктуации. Нужны ли запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

В «**Песне о разлуке**» из х/ф «Гардемарины, вперед!» (1987) есть четверостишие:

*И глянет мгла из всех болот и всех теснин,/
И засвистит веселый кнут над пегой парою./
Ты запоешь свою тоску, летя во тьму один,/
А я, одна, заплачу песню старую.*

Вопрос:

Следует ли убрать запятые из четвертой строки?:

*А я одна заплачу песню старую.*

Comment: скорее всего нет, хотя в песне вообще не так поётся, а: а я одна - заплачу песню старую.

Answer (score 1):

Если обособление **есть в тексте**, то ничего менять **не надо**:

*И глянет мгла из всех болот и всех теснин,/ И засвистит веселый кнут над пегой парою./ Ты запоешь свою тоску, летя во тьму **один**,/ А я, **однА**, заплачу песню старую.*

1. Это авторский выбор **обособления** слова "один", кода оба решения **возможны**.  В данном случае **подчеркивается** соответствие: *ты летишь **один**, а я, **тоже однА**, заплачу.*
2. На письме ставятся **запятые**, в устной речи делается выделение слова **паузами**. Слово "одна" выделено **ударением**.
3. **Словарь:**  II. **в зн. прил.** 1. Без других, в отдельности от других, в одиночестве. Я живу одна.
4. Слово "одна" является **дуплексивом:**, оно связано с подлежащим и сказуемым: *Я одна, заплачу одна.*

**ПРАВИЛО**

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)**   Пункт 7. Одиночное (нераспространенное) определение обособляется: 1) если несет на себе значительную **смысловую нагрузку.**

Answer (score 1):

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1. Вы сами написали текст с запятой, **а зачем?** У вас же был нотный архив, где никакой запятой не было.
2. Я даю ответ: обособление —  это **авторский выбор**. Автор имеет право **подчеркнуть значимое слово.**
3. Вы считаете, что все дело **в примерах:** ведь никто не ставит запятую. Вы можете это **объяснить по правилам**, какова грамматика предложения?
4. Да, необособленный вариант более **частотный** (опять же почему, вы это можете **объяснить**?).
5. **Но авторское обособление тоже возможно!** Не надо думать, что в пунктуации у нас полная унификация. Об этом сказано у Розенталя:

Если в области орфографии желательна и необходима полная унификация, то к пунктуации это требование **неприменимо.** Особенности русской пунктуации — в присущей ей **многофункциональности** знаков препинания и широкой их взаимозаменяемости, в своеобразии **индивидуально-авторского** использования знаков препинания, в гибкости пунктуационной системы, позволяющей выявлять не только смысловую сторону текста, но и стилистические его оттенки. Все это исключает **формальный подход** к соблюдению правил.

Ваш вопрос был о правилах пунктуации? Я даю вам цитату Розенталя из  **[предисловия к его справочнику](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php)**.

В пунктуации действуют три принципа: **семантика, грамматика, интонация**. Я дала вам **объяснения** по всем трем принципам.

Comment: К пункту 1 в Вашем комментарии: Текст с запятыми был приведен, согласно сайту «Кино-Театр RU». В том виде текст (с запятыми) — на многих сайтах: https://www.kino-teatr.ru/kino/movie/sov/1332/song/ Затем, в моем комментарии ниже, была сверка текста песни с «Нотным Архивом России»; с «Нотного Апхива» текст обнаружен позднее.

Comment: Спасибо.  Это нужно было указать (с какими источниками работаете). Тогда  я не понимаю вашего ответа.  Какой вы делаете вывод?  Что хотели узнать на форуме? Что узнали?

Comment: На форуме задаются вопросы. Их наличие выявляет интеллектуальное содержание для ориентации в подобных моментах русского языка. Если рассматривать форум, как сборище «ты мне, я — тебе», т.е. «узнай мое, а я — твое», то это — пустое словотрепачество между лицами с дворовой ментальностью, где группка избранных выясняет отношения «по понятиям». Если обращаться к вопросам, как к энциклопедической подсказке (не исключая каверзных моментов в вопросе), то содержание контента не приравнивается к околоплинтусной планке дворовых разборок.

Comment: Нет проблем, пусть будет по-вашему. Мне  по поводу запятых бы узнать. Нужны они в песне или нет? Об этом мой вопрос.  Вы теперь знаете, нужны или нет?  И почему нужны или нет?

Comment: Ваш ответ правилен — простановка запятых в предложении зависит от обособлений в тексте. Но ни к «Песне о разлуке», ни к песне «На теплоходе музыка играет» данное правило, как видно из «Нотного Архива», не относится.

Comment: Тогда мы друг друга не поняли. Правда, я вашу формулировку и сейчас не понимаю: "простановка запятых в предложении зависит от обособлений в тексте".  Кстати, у нас не форум, а сайт вопросов и ответов. К содержанию вопросов и ответов предъявляются определенные требования. Ту особо не забалуешь, модерация строгая.

Comment: Пунктуационных правил много. Сообщение с портала: «Пожалуйста, избегайте развернутых обсуждений в комментариях». И далее предложение переместиться по ссылке в чат. Более подробно о правилах пунктуации — это к личному преподавателю, в дискуссионных рамках учебной программы. Ну а мой вопрос, все же, состоял в том, нужна ли была запятая в данном случае или нет? Вы сослались на выдержки из энциклопедических знаний, говорите: «обособление — это авторский выбор», но конкретно на вопрос не ответили. Так что, извините, вопрос, еще раз, состоял в том, чтобы дать правильный  ответ на приведенный пример.

Comment: Факультативность обособления фиксируется правилами, а также определяется по грамматике. Нет обособления для определений: 3) связанных по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, в состав которого они входят. И вот это как раз наш случай. Обычно нет обособления, но оно возможно, если автор хочет подчеркнуть значимость слова.  Что же еще вы хотите услышать? Или у вас другая грамматика? А какая?  назовите, интересно же. Очень люблю грамматику разбирать.  Если этого нет в ответе, то и начинается болтовня в свободном режиме. Другими словами, обозначение своих мнений.

Comment: У меня два критерия: знание грамматики и хорошее чувство языка. Это мои оценки при общении. Причем чувство языка я могу измерить: как кто слышит русскую речь.

Comment: Да, верно: обособление возможно, если значимость слова подчеркивается. Но следовало, отвечая на мой вопрос — вновь повторю — преподносить не только заученные наизусть правила русского языка задающему вопрос, а подключить было и ментальный процесс при рассмотрении конкретного примера. В известной телепередаче «Что? Где? Когда?» такое «не прокатило бы», и если вопрос поставлен был там «сколько будет 5+5?», то, произнося в качестве ответа законы сложения, игроки бы не отделались бы.

Comment: Лирика! Вот пример: Тире часто заменяет двоеточие, а иногда и запятую можно поставить. А правило где? Так где же оно, можете сказать? В языке полно факультативных задач.  Я умею их решать, а вы? Могу и без правил задачи решать, а вы?  Мне правила для отчетности нужны, ссылки же требуют.

Comment: Ладно, потом договорим, а то некогда. Может быть, договорим.

Answer (score 0):

В искомой строке "одна" обособлено в значении "будучи", что указует (на) и подчёркивает одиночество.

В исполнении Камбуровой я слышу это обособление.

Answer (score 0):

На сайте «Нотный Архив России» http://www.notarhiv.ru/ruskomp/lebedev/stranizi/Razluka.html в четвертой строке текста «Песни о разлуке» нет никаких запятых. Также весь текст данной песни на этом портале значительно разнится с текстом той же песни, приведенном на других порталах. Сравните с «Нотным Архивом России»:

ПЕСНЯ О РАЗЛУКЕ

Муз. В.Лебедева,/
сл. Ю.Ряшенцева,/
из к/ф «Гардемарины, вперед!»

И глянет мгла из всех болот, из всех теснин,/
И засвистит веселый кнут над пегой парою.../
Ты запоешь свою тоску, летя во тьму один,/
А я одна заплачу песню старую.

Разлука — вот извечный враг российских грез,/
Разлука — вот полночный тать в счастливой полночи./
И лишь земля из-под колес,/
И не расслышать из-за гроз/
Ни ваших шпаг, ни наших слез, ни слов о помощи!

Какой беде из века в век обречены?/
Какой нужде мы платим дань, прощаясь с милыми?/
И для чего нам эта явь такие дарит сны,/
Что дивный свет над песнями унылыми?

Быть может, нам не размыкать счастливых рук?/
Быть может, нам распрячь коней на веки вечные?/
Но стонет север, кличет юг,/
И вновь колес прощальный стук,/
И вот судьба разбита вдруг/
О версты встречные!

Загляните еще в «Нотный Архив» и посмотрите на аналогичный пример: Песня в исполнении Ольги Зарубиной «На теплоходе музыка играет».

На теплоходе музыка играет,/
А я одна стою на берегу./
Машу рукой, а сердце замирает
И ничего поделать не могу./

Во второй строке песни нет запятых.